# Longest equal subsequences

Tags: code-golf, array

## Definitions

- A subsequence may not be contiguous, e.g. `[1, 1, 1]` is a subsequence of `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]`.
- An equal subsequence is a subsequence in which every element is equal.
- The longest equal subsequence may not be unique, e.g. `[1, 1]` and `[2, 2]` are both longest equal subsequences of `[2, 1, 1, 2]`.

## Input

A non-empty list of positive integers in one of the format below:

- as the native implementation of an array of positive integers in your language
- as a string of newline-separated integers in decimal
- as a string of newline-separated integers in unary
- any other reasonable formats

## Output

All of the longest equal subsequences in any order in one of the formats below:

- as a 2D nested array in your language (if the input is an array)
- as a flattened array with the equal elements being contiguous
- any other reasonable format

## Scoring

Although we are looking for something long, the code used should be as short as possible in terms of number of bytes, since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Testcases

Inputs:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Outputs:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[1, 1], [2, 2]]
[[1, 1], [2, 2]]
[[1, 1, 1]]
```

Note that for the outputs above, any order is valid.

A flattened array is also valid, as long as the equal elements are contiguous.

Comment: It would be simpler to talk of “most frequent elements” IMO: subsequences are used when the order is important, but here, every permutation of the input has the same set of allowed correct outputs.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Sorry, I've edited the question.

Comment: Does a flat list work for output? E.g. `1 2 3`, `1 1 2 2`, `1 1 2 2`, `1 1 1`?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien saying yes would invalidate most of the answers here...

Comment: @LeakyNun As in, is it an acceptable alternative?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien yes.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ĠLÐṀị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39kgc/hCQ93Njzc3f3/cPujpjVHJz3cOQNIR/7/H82lEG2oo2Cko2AcqwNnA5EhEtcYQwQubgIS54oFAA)

#### How it works

```
ĠLÐṀị  Main link. Argument: A (array)

Ġ      Group; partition the indices of A by their corresponding values.
 LÐṀ   Select all index arrays with maximal length.
    ị  Unindex; retrieve the items of A at the specified indices.
```

Comment: I thought Jelly doesn't have a maximum quick...

Comment: It's technically a *maximal* quick, but yes, it does.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
⊇ᶠ=ˢlᵍh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/@oq/3htgW2pxflPNzam/H/f7ShjoKJjoIRmDQGMwxj/0cBAA)

### Explanation

```
⊇ᶠ=ˢlᵍh
⊇ᶠ        Find all subsequences
  =ˢ      Keeping only those for which all elements are equal
    lᵍ    Group by length
      h   Take the first group
```

`⊇`'s natural order generates the longest subsequences first, so those are the ones that end up in the first group.

Comment: Oh hey, another Brachylogist.

Comment: Somehow you and me must have missed each other repeatedly in the Brachylog chat; I've been using it for months, and was surprised to learn that apparently someone else besides Fatalize was too.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
S.M/Q
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S.M%2FQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+2%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+1%5D&debug=0)

Explanation:

This is implicitly `S.M/QZQ`. `.M` is the maximal function, so `.M/QZQ` selects all elements where the value of `/QZ`, count the number of occurrences of the element in the input, is maximal. `S` then sorts the list so that identical elements are contiguous.

Answer (score 3):

### bash, 66 bytes

```
sort|uniq -c|sort -rn|awk 'NR==1{a=$1}$1==a{for(i=a;i--;)print$2}'
```

This seems like it should be way shorter, but I can't figure out how.

```
sort                  # sort the input
|uniq -c              # group runs of identical lines and prefix with count
|sort -rn             # sort by count, with largest at top
|awk '                # pipe to awk...
  NR==1{a=$1}         # on the first line, set the variable "a" to field 1
  $1==a{              # on any line, if first field is a (max count)...
    for(i=a;i--;)     # a times...
    print$2           # print the second field
  }
'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@cX1RSU5qXWaigm1wD4ijoFuXVJJZnK6j7BdnaGlYn2qoY1qoY2tomVqflF2lk2iZaZ@rqWmsWFGXmlagY1ar//2/IZcRlDMSGAA)

Thanks to [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun) for 3 bytes!

Comment: [3 bytes off](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@cX1RSU5qXWaigm1wD4ijoFuXVJJZnK6j7BdnaGlYn2qoY1qoY2tomVqflF2lk2iZaZ@rqWmsWFGXmlagY1ar//2/IZcRlDMSGAA)

Comment: Consider updating your explanation

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>68</s> 63 bytes

```python
lambda x:sorted(n for n in x if x.count(n)/max(map(x.count,x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S1OwVYj5n5OYm5SSqFBhVZxfVJKaopGnkJZfpJCnkJmnUKGQmaZQoZecX5pXopGnqZ@bWKGRm1igARXSqdDU1PxfUJSZV6KQphFtqKNgpKNgHKvJhSYERIaYosa4JODSJmDp/wA)

Comment: Would like to see an answer in Python 3 :p

Comment: Porting this one is trivial: just replace `print` with `return`.

Comment: Oh, I thought Python 3 doesn't have `map`.

Comment: It's a bit different in 3 (returns a generator and truncates longer iterables if there are more than two arguments), but it's there.

Comment: I thought Python had a built-in for this

Comment: @BetaDecay Without an external library, I doubt it. And even then, verbose imports are oftentimes longer than rolling your own.

Comment: @BetaDecay The closest I know to a Python builtin for this is [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter): for example `Counter([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]).most_common()` returns `[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1)]` and you could walk the list till the count decreases (here after just the first element). But that would be a lot more verbose, even after the import.

Comment: I have added another acceptable alternative which might help you golf off some bytes.

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Dennis It's my responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 23 bytes

```
;╗⌠;╜ck⌡M;♂NM╗⌠N╜=⌡░♂FS
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@2/9aOr0Rz0LgNSc5OxHPQt9rR/NbPLzhYj6AUVtgYKPpk0EiroFA7kOj6au@v8/2lBHwUhHwRhMGsYCAA), or [run all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#e9Sz4L/1o6nTH/UsAFJzkrMf9Sz0tX40s8nPFyLqBxS1BQo@mjYRKOoW/B@kIPN/dLShjoKRjoJxrI4ClAlEhgieMboAXNgEJBwLAA)!

Thanks to Leaky Nun for pointing out a one-byte improvement that really should've been obvious to me

-3 bytes from relaxed output format

Explanation:

```
;╗⌠;╜ck⌡M;♂NM╗⌠N╜=⌡░♂FS
;╗                        save a copy of the input to register 0
  ⌠;╜ck⌡M                 for each value in the input list:
   ;                        make a copy on the stack
    ╜c                      count the occurrences in the input list (from register 0)
      k                     make a list: [value, count]
         ;♂N             make a copy, take last value of each list in the 2D list
            M╗           store the maximum count in register 0
              ⌠N╜=⌡░     filter the other copy of the list of [value, count] lists:
               N╜=         take items where the count equals the maximum count
                    ♂FS  take first items (values) and sort them
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), <s>55</s> <s>52</s> 43 bytes

```
sorted rle toarr:[1#]map MAX@K[1#K=]YES rld
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#09AwVDBSMNZUANNGCoZQljESG8I3AfI1FaoV8/4X5xeVpKYoFOWkKpTkJxYVWUUbKsfmJhYo@DpGOHgDOd62sZGuwUAFKf/zFIpSC4oUCkpLFNQVbO2ABIgJFssHMmoVgPr@AwA)

Works by run-length encoding the input, sorting by occurrences, keeping occurances for which the number of occurrences is maximal, and run length decoding. Outputs through a flat list, as is acceptable by the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>42</s> <s>31</s> 25 bytes

*Thanks @GregMartin for 5 bytes and @MartinEnder for another byte!*

```
MaximalBy[Length]@*Gather
```

### Explanation

```
MaximalBy[Length]@*Gather  (*                       {1, 2, 3, 2, 1}       *)
                   Gather  (* Gather same numbers:  {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3}} *)
                 @*        (* Function composition                        *)
MaximalBy[Length]          (* Find longest:         {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}      *)
```

Comment: You can save 5 bytes with `Gather@#~MaximalBy~Length&`.

Comment: @GregMartin and then `MaximalBy[Length]@*Gather`.

Comment: I have added another acceptable alternative which might help you golf off some bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
{x{b=|/b:#'x}#.=x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6quqE6yrdFPslJWr6hV1rOtqOXi0khLyLLXVFdQiskDYqVoQx0FIx0F41guBSgTiAwRPGN0AbiwCUhYCQD8oxYl)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 138 bytes

```
lambda l:[[x[0]]*x[1] for x in next(__import__('itertools').groupby(__import__('collections').Counter(l).most_common(),lambda x:x[1]))[1]]
```

Comment: `itertools` is never the shortest :p

Comment: I have added another acceptable alternative which might help you golf off some bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 47 bytes

```matlab
[~,b,c]=mode(input(0));disp([repmat(c,1,b){:}])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@x9dp5Okkxxrm5ufkqqRmVdQWqJhoKlpnZJZXKARXZRakJtYopGsY6iTpFltVRur@f9/tKGOgpGOgjGYNIwFAA)

#### Explanation

The second and third outputs of `mode` (obtained as `[~,b,c]=mode(...)`) respectively give the number of repetitions (`b`) and a column cell array (`c`) of the most repeated elements in the input (`input(0)`) . The cell array `c` is then repeated horizontally `b` times (`repmat(c,1,b)`), converted to a comma-separated list (`{:}`) and contatenated horizontally (`[...]`) to give a numeric matrix, which is displayed (`disp(...)`).

Comment: I have added another acceptable alternative which might help you golf off some bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
3#XMg1bX"&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2@sHOGbbpgUoaT2/3@0oYGOghEQG0NpQ4NYAA)

#### Explanation

Similar to my Octave answer. Consider input `[10, 20, 30, 20, 10]` as an example.

```
3#XM   % Three-output version of mode function. Gives the first mode, the
       % number of repetitions, and a cell array with all modes
       % STACK: 10, 2, {10; 20}
g      % Convert from cell array to matrix
       % STACK: 10, 2, [10; 20]
1      % Push 1
       % STACK: 10, 2, [10; 20], 1
b      % Bubble up in the stack
       % STACK: 10, [10; 20], 1, 2
X"     % Repeat those number of times vertically and horizontally
       % STACK: 10, [10, 10; 20, 20]
&      % Specify that implicit display will show only the top of the stack.
       % Since this is singleton cell array that contains a matrix, that 
       % matrix is directly displayed
```

Comment: I have added another acceptable alternative which might help you golf off some bytes.

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks for letting me know

Comment: It is my responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 5 bytes

Outputs a flat list in order

```
.M¹Ã{
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6/ne2jn4ebq//@jDXUUjHQUIKSxjoIJkB0LAA)

Comment: I have added another acceptable alternative which might help you golf off some bytes.

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks for the notification :)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 22 bytes

```
{$e`z~\__:e>f=.*\]ze~}
```

This is an anonymous block (function) that takes the input from the top of the stack and repaces it with the output. The output is a flattened array withequal elements being contiguous.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#izZUMFIwBmLD2P/VKqkJVXUx8fFWqXZptnpaMbFVqXW1/@sK/gMA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `[10  20  30  20  10 ]` as an example.

```
{      e# Begin block
       e#   STACK: [10 20 30 20 10]
  $    e#   Sort
       e#   STACK: [10 10 20 20 30]
  e`   e#   Run-length encoding
       e#   STACK: [[2 10] [2 20] [1 30]]
  z    e#   Zip
       e#   STACK: [[2 2 1] [10 20 30]]
  ~    e#   Dump array contents onto the stack
       e#   STACK: [2 2 1] [10 20 30]
  \    e#   Swap
       e#   STACK: [10 20 30] [2 2 1]
  __   e#   Duplicate twice
       e#   STACK: [10 20 30] [2 2 1] [2 2 1] [2 2 1]
  :e>  e#   Fold maximum over array. Gives the maximum of the array
       e#   STACK: [10 20 30] [2 2 1] [2 2 1] 2
  f=   e#   Map "is equal" with number (2) over the array ([2 2 1])
       e#   STACK: [10 20 30] [2 2 1] [1 1 0]
  .*   e#   Vectorized multiplication
       e#   STACK: [10 20 30] [2 2 0]
  \    e#   Swap
       e#   STACK: [2 2 0] [10 20 30]
  ]    e#   Pack into array
       e#   STACK: [[2 2 0] [10 20 30]]
  z    e#   Zip
       e#   STACK: [[2 10] [2 20] [0 30]]
  e~   e#   Run-length decoding
       e#   STACK: [10 10 20 20]
}      e# End block
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 58 bytes

```
sub{sort grep$x{$_}>$m,grep{$/=$x{$_}++;$m=$/if$m<$/;1}@_}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
→kLk=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbpGyfbNv///9HG@oY6RgDsWEsAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ü üÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=/CD8yg&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDIsIDFdCi1R)

```
ü üÊ     :Implicit input of array
ü        :Group & sort by value
  üÊ     :Group & sort by length
         :Implicit output of last element
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way to wait for a certain amount of time, or run a block until condition in Japt?

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

```
/=~=~$$,$@
```

```
/=~=~$$,$@
   =~       # group
     $      # the input
      $     # by its own values,
 =~         # now group each of these groups
       ,$   # by their lengths
            # (group of longest groups comes last),
/           # fold over this list-of-lists from right
         @  # always returning the second argument
            # (so this fold just returns the last item,
            # which is the list of the longest groups
            # of values)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

Requires `⎕ML←3` which is default on many systems.

#### Program: `s/⍨(⌈/=⊢)≢¨s←⊂⍨(⍋⊃¨⊂)⎕`

`⎕` get numeric (evaluated) input

`(`…`)` tacit function
 `⍋` the indices of ascending items
 `⊃¨` each pick from
 `⊂` the entire array

`⊂⍨` partition by cutting at its increases

`s←` store as *s*

`≢¨` tally each

`(`…`)` tacit function
 `⌈/` the maximum (tally)
 `=` equals
 `⊢` the argument (the tallies)

`s/⍨` filter *s* with that

#### Function: `{s/⍨(⌈/=⊢)≢¨s←⊂⍨⍵[⍋⍵]}`

`{`…`}` anonymous function where argument is `⍵`

`⍵[⍋⍵]` sort (lit. index with indices of ascending items)

`⊂⍨` partition by cutting at its increases

`s←` store as *s*

`≢¨` tally each

`(`…`)` tacit function
 `⌈/` the maximum (tally)
 `=` equals
 `⊢` the argument (the tallies)

`s/⍨` filter *s* with that
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#U9Z71DfV1@dR2wRjrkcd7Wn/i/Uf9a7QeNTToW/7qGuR5qPORYdWFAOlH3U1gSV6ux91NR9aAeRqAnX@B@rhSgdKV@PX96h3azRIa@/W2Nr/aVyGOgpGOgrGXDAWEBnCOcZofLioCUiUKx0mAGeBVacroOqG8VF1AwA)

Comment: I have added another acceptable alternative which might help you golf off some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 24 bytes

```
{$e`_$W=0=\{0=1$=},e~\;}
```

I wanted to do this in 05ab1e, but I gave up :P

This is a block. Input and output are arrays on the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#izZUMFIwBmLD2P/VKqkJ8Qa2BrYx1Qa2hiq2tTpWiVapdTHWtf/rEv4DAA)

Explanation:

```
{                      e# Stack:                | [1 2 3 2 1]
 $                     e# Sort:                 | [1 1 2 2 3]
  e`                   e# RLE encode:           | [[2 1] [2 2] [1 3]]
    _$W=               e# Copy elements:        | [[2 1] [2 2] [1 3]] [2 1]
       0=              e# First element:        | [[2 1] [2 2] [1 3]] 2
         \             e# Swap:                 | 2 [[2 1] [2 2] [1 3]]
          {0=1$=},     e# Filter where x[0]==2: | 2 [[2 1] [2 2]]
                  e~   e# RLE decode:           | 2 [1 1 2 2]
                    \; e# Delete back:          | [1 1 2 2]
                      }
```

Comment: This only works if the smallest integer belongs to the most common elements. You'll need `$W=` instead of the first `0=`.

Comment: I have added another acceptable alternative which might help you golf off some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 69 Bytes

```php
<?print_r(preg_grep("#".max($r=array_count_values($_GET))."#",$r));
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4708cb38ce9cd4c658637033dbd5d755d584cc3)

### Output Format

key = value , value = count

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
)
```

### PHP, 96 Bytes

```php
<?foreach($_GET as$v)$r[$m[]=count($l=preg_grep("#^{$v}$#",$_GET))][$v]=$l;print_r($r[max($m)]);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/afbc1269ed2cdc2da52e73ce655e42ad924c8bec)

### Output Format

1D Key= value

2D Key = position in the input array for each value

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
            [3] => 2
        )

)
```

### PHP, 97 Bytes

```php
<?foreach($_GET as$v)$r[count($l=preg_grep("#^{$v}$#",$_GET))][$v]=$l;ksort($r);print_r(end($r));
```

Comment: I have added another acceptable alternative which might help you golf off some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>84</s> 83 bytes

Returns a sorted flattened array.

```js
a=>a.sort().filter((_,i)=>b[i]==Math.min(...b),b=a.map(i=>a.filter(j=>i-j).length))
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>a.sort().filter((_,i)=>b[i]==Math.min(...b),b=a.map(i=>a.filter(j=>i-j).length))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 2, 3])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 2, 2, 1])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 2, 3, 2, 1])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1])))
```

Comment: I have added another acceptable alternative which might help you golf off some bytes.

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks for the notification.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 65 bytes

```
#(let[P partition-by C count](last(P C(sort-by C(P +(sort %))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(def f #(->> %
             (sort-by      identity)   ; sort so that identical values are one after another, same as sort
             (partition-by identity)   ; partition by identity (duh!)
             (sort-by      count)      ; sort by item count
             (partition-by count)      ; partition by item count
             last))                    ; get the last partition
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 145 Bytes

```cs
l=>{var t=Enumerable.Range(0,l.Max()+1).Select(i=>l.Count(a=>a==i));return t.Select((a,i)=>Enumerable.Repeat(i,a)).Where(d=>d.Count()==t.Max());}
```

This must be possible better as well, however I'm kind of stuck.

**Explanation**

```cs
l =>                                                   //Takes the list
{                                                      //...
    var t = Enumerable.Range(0, l.Max() + 1)           //Makes a range till the count, so that the items together with their indices are double defined (i.e. the items are 0,1,2,3... and the indices are the same)
                      .Select(i =>                     //Takes the items
                          l.Count(a => a == i));       //And replaces them with the count of themselves in the list (so the item has the index with its old value and the count as it's actual value)
    return t.Select((a, i) =>                          //Then it takes this list and selects the items together with the indices
        Enumerable.Repeat(i, a))                       //Repeats them as often as they appeared in the list
                  .Where(d => d.Count() == t.Max());   //And just keeps those which appear the maximum amount of times
};                                                     //...
```

Probably a totally different approach would be much shorter, so the C# challenge is still open :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.reject{|i|a.map{|j|a.count j}.max>a.count(i)}.sort}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7ON@a9rl1idqFeUmpWaXFJdk1mTqJebWFBdkwVkJOeX5pUoZNUCRSrsoFyNTM1aveL8opLa/@UZmTmpCumpJcVcCgoFCml6yYk5OQqpZYk5GirxmlypeSn/ow11FIx0FIxjuaAsIDKEc4zR@HBRE5AoAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics`, 46 bytes

```factor
[ all-subsets [ all-eq? ] filter all-longest ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xck7DsIwEATQ3qeYCxCJTwUFJaKhQVQohWNtgiXHdrwbCRTl7CZKCj5bjGbe1tpISPl2PV9Oe7RaHoUJbWW9ntgaRpNCH61vwNT15A3xpxX0lKQZMZHIKybrBQelBoXpBqyxwRbj19pMOf58/2XR3ayjyndo51bcV0zCWBZ1R5SorRNKM7jgG2JBmVsdUeQ3)

- `all-subsets` Get all the subsets of the input
- `[ all-eq? ] filter` Get the ones where all the elements are the same
- `all-longest` Get all the longest of these